# Use variables in Eloquent query / Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

In my Laravel 5.2 controller, I'm executing a request with Eloquent ORM :

```
$products = Product::where('first_condition', 'first_condition_value')
                            ->where('second_condition', 'second_condition_value')
                            ->get();
```

This request works fine and gives me a list of the products that match the two conditions.

Ideally, I would like to generate a `$request` variable and use it in my request:

```
$request = "where('first_condition', 'first_condition_value')->where('second_condition', 'second_condition_value')"
```

I didn't manage to make this code run.

To give you more perspective, the request can have multiple conditions from 2 to n so I would like to generate it with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your extra conditions in an array and loop them as the following snippet:

```
<?php
$query = Product::where('first_condition', 'first_condition_value');

$conditions = array(
    'second_condition' => 'second_condition_value',
    'third_condition' => 'third_condition_value',
);

foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
    $query->where($key, $value);
}

$products = $query->get();
```